# MVC code to print on standard Envelopes / Labels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing, envelope

Does anyone know of any opensource code, or have any code I can use, that can be used in an MVC application to print (addresses) on envelopes (where the size can be selected) or to standard sized labels (again with a size etc can be selected).

This must be a common scenario, but I can't find any reusable code

Answer (score 0):

You can call `window.print()` from javascript but you can't specify the paper size etc. That's up to the user to select on the print dialog box. `window.print()` will print the entire page though, if you want to print only selected parts of the page you can use media css to hide elements from the print output. i.e.

```
@media print
{
    .noprint {display:none;}
}
```

and add the class `.noprint` to the elements that you don't want to get printed.